# macOS - ntpd uses more than 100% of CPU

Tags: macos, cpu, activity-monitor

it happens couple times every day, my MacBook becomes extremely slow. When I check Activity Monitor, I see that `ntpd` process uses more than 100% of my CPU (usually around 140-180%).

If I kill it (Force Quit), MacBook starts working as usual. But it will happen again in several hours. How can I fix this issue? It becomes really annoying

It started after one of the software updates (not sure exactly when).

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013) with **macOS 10.12.3**

Comment: Go to `System Preferences > Date and Time` (unlock if needed) and uncheck `Set date and time automatically`. Close System Preferences, then reopen and re-check `Set date and time automatically`. Make sure the time server info is correct for your location on the planet.

Comment: just did it, will check in a few hours if it helped, thanks

Comment: @IconDaemon looks like it helped. If you can post your solution as an answer, I will confirm it

Answer (score 37):

Go to System Preferences > Date and Time and uncheck Set date and time automatically. Close System Preferences, then reopen and re-check Set date and time automatically

Comment: Thanks for answer - this helped resolve my 200% utilized process.  I presume this is an OS bug?  Has it been reported to Apple?

Comment: What a broken Mac is, I constantly fight some internall stuff eating CPU. Today is ntpd.

Comment: I tried just unchecking because I didn't mind if it did not auto-update, and that was not sufficient.  I had to uncheck and recheck to fix the problem, and then I could set the check however I liked.  Also `ntpq -p` in the answer below was useful as a diagnostic because it timed out until the problem was fixed and CPU back near zero.

Comment: On one occasion, this did not work, and I was told by our help desk about an alternate fix:  On the Date and Time tab, I had to change the server to Apple and then back to our work server.  (There are authentication-related reasons to keep it pointed at the work-managed server.)

Answer (score 5):

Check if the NTP servers you have configured are correct and reachable.

Open a Terminal window and run

```
ntpq -p
```

This is the output I got on my system which had ntpd using around 80-90% cpu.

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*aer-foo5d20-dc- .GPS.            1 u   23   64   17   17.888   20.617   2.226
 aer-foo6t20-dc- .GPS.            1 u   23   64   17   17.938   20.598   2.211
 defra1-ntp-001. .INIT.          16 u    -  68m    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

This shows that I had 3 ntp server configured, the 2 first ones are ok but the 3rd one was unreachable (I'm no NTP expert but refid=.INIT., st=16 and reach=0 all seem to indicate something is wrong).

So I went to System Preferences > Date and Time , where indeed I had 3 ntp servers configured: 2 inside my company's network, and `time.apple.com` - so nothing resembling "defra1-ntp-001".
Assuming "defra1-ntp-001" referred to time.apple.com I removed that one, and this resolved my problem.

Of course in my specific case, probably time.apple.com was unreachable because it is blocked by my company's firewall, so I don't recommend removing it as a general solution. Instead check your 'ntpq -p' output and try to determine which server is causing the problem and remove that one (and if none are left, add a known good one).

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the query timed out.  Then I followed the suggestion from the accepted answer and in System Preferences > Date and Time saw that my system is pointing to my corp ntp server.  Then I ran the query again and this time it worked.  Maybe some bug related to switching to VPN?